# Spring boot remote address in standalone Apache Tomcat instance

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, reverse-proxy, tomcat8

I have a spring boot 1.2 web application  is deployed on standalone tomcat.
I need to authorize an url based on remote IP. 
In case of embedded tomcat , we can use

server.tomcat.remote_ip_header= x-forwarded-for

How do we configure, when deployed in standalone tomcat.

Note : 
I did try   RemoteIpValve of tomcat by setting remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"  and it did not work  and My tomcat is behind a web Application firewall.

without changing tomcat settings etc, can we tell spring security to look for remote ip in  x-forwarded-for(in stand alone tomcat deployement)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Remote IP Filter available with Tomcat. There are many such filters available.

Please see (Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_IP_Filter)

You can configure these filters in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml which will be available for all web application or you can do it in web applications web.xml.